# Execute external groovy script from Maven

Tags: maven, groovy

I have a **maven** project with nothing related to **groovy** in `pom.xml`. And I just want to execute a groovy script `test.groovy` in the root of my project with access to all project's classes.

so I try to run an command:

```
mvn groovy:execute -Dsource=test.groovy
```

but it tells me that:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:groovy-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (default-cli) on project modules-journal:
The parameters 'source' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:groovy-maven-plugin:1.5:execute are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

what is wrong?

`mvn groovy:shell` works perfectly, but I want to run predefined script.

Comment: does `test.groovy` exist in the current directory?  Does `mvn groovy:execute -Dsource=./test.groovy` work?

Comment: Yes it really exists. But `-Dsource=./test.groovy` and `-Dsource=[full-path-to-script]` gives same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails with groovy-maven-plugin in version 1.5, but it works great with version 2.0.

Comment: Oyee! `mvn org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.0:execute -Dsource=test.groovy -Dscope=test` finally works for me. Thank you.